# Is it possible to determine whether this series is convergent?

Tags: divergent-series

One often comes across stability regions when looking at [explicit](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Stability_region_for_Euler_method.svg) and [implicit](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Stability_region_for_BDF1.svg) Euler's method (for $\dot{x}=\lambda x$). But I have never come across such region for Verlet, say for the ODE $\ddot{x}=\lambda x$:
$$
x_{n+1} = 2x_n - x_{n-1} + h^2\lambda x_n
$$
So I thought I would try this my self. After initially writing out quite a few terms to find a pattern I found the following expression.
First I will define the "growth" parameter $\alpha$ as
$$
\alpha = 2 + h^2 \lambda
$$
$$
x_{k+1} = x_1 \sum^{\lfloor \frac{k}{2}\rfloor}_{m=0} \left(\frac{(-1)^m \alpha^{k-2m}}{m!} \prod^{2m-1}_{i=m}(k-i)\right) - x_0 \sum^{\lfloor \frac{k-1}{2}\rfloor}_{m=0} \left(\frac{(-1)^m \alpha^{k-1-2m}}{m!} \prod^{2m-1}_{i=m}(k-1-i)\right)
$$
For instance for $k=10$ this yields:
$$
x_{11} = x_1 \left(\alpha^{10} - 9\alpha^8 + 28\alpha^6 - 35\alpha^4 + 15\alpha^2 - 1\right) - x_0 \left(\alpha^9 - 8\alpha^7 + 21\alpha^5 - 20\alpha^3 + 5\alpha\right)
$$
However I am wondering if these terms would converge or diverge depending on the value of $\alpha$. I have no idea how to approach this since there is product within summation and I already found it quite an achievement when I found this expression.

This might be a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18764/behaviour-of-a-numerical-solution-of-an-ode), since it also looks a the stability behavior of Verlet, but I would like to known whether these expressions would converge or diverge for large $k$ depending on $\alpha$.

**Edit:**
The answer of Did did convince me that approaching this problem with matrices would be the easier way to go, but Did did not proof that what values for $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$ and $c_4$ are, so it might be possible that the limit of $n$ to infinity would not blow up.

First I will, for clarity sake, define the matrix notation of the problem which has to solved,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}x_{n+1} \\ x_{n}\end{bmatrix} = A \begin{bmatrix}x_{n} \\ x_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}\alpha & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Thus by multiplying the initial positions vector $n$ times by $A$ will allow you to find the positions vector $n$ steps further,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}x_{n+1} \\ x_{n}\end{bmatrix} = A^n \begin{bmatrix}x_{1} \\ x_{0}\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The values for those constants can be derived with the help of [eigen decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EigenDecomposition.html) of a matrix $A$,

$$
A = PDP^{-1},
$$

Matrix $D$ is a diagonal matrix with each element of the diagonal containing one of the eigenvalues of $A$, which are

$$
\lambda_1 = \frac{\alpha + \sqrt{\alpha^2 - 4}}{2},
$$

$$
\lambda_2 = \frac{\alpha - \sqrt{\alpha^2 - 4}}{2}.
$$

By expressing $\lambda_1$ in $\lambda_2$ it can be shown that

$$
\lambda_1 = \lambda_2^{-1}.
$$

In order to keep the rest of the equations a little less bulky I will use $\lambda$ for the first eigenvalue and thus the second eigenvalues will be $\lambda^{-1}$, instead of the parameter $\alpha$. The resulting matrices $D$, $P$ and $P^{-1}$ are therefore

$$
D = \begin{bmatrix}\lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda^{-1}\end{bmatrix},
$$

$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}\lambda & \lambda^{-1} \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix},
$$

$$
P^{-1} = \frac{1}{\lambda^2 - 1}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda & -1 \\ -\lambda & \lambda^2\end{bmatrix}.
$$

By substituting these matrices for $A$ in the expressing for the positions vector $n$ steps further yields

$$
\begin{bmatrix}x_{n+1} \\ x_{n}\end{bmatrix} = P D^n P^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}x_{1} \\ x_{0}\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{\lambda^2 - 1} \begin{bmatrix}\lambda & \lambda^{-1} \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\lambda^n & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda^{-n}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\lambda & -1 \\ -\lambda & \lambda^2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_{1} \\ x_{0}\end{bmatrix}.
$$

When multiplying this all out you will get

$$
x_{n+1} = x_1 \frac{\lambda^{n+2} - \lambda^{-n}}{\lambda^{2} - 1} + x_0 \frac{\lambda^{1-n} - \lambda^{n+1}}{\lambda^{2} - 1}.
$$

I am not sure how to proceed here, since $\lambda$ can be complex, when $2<\alpha<-2$, in which case its magnitude will also always be one. I also did some numerical calculations with MATLAB and it seemed to be stable for $2<\alpha<-2$, however I do not know how to proof this. And stability regions also include complex values for $h$.

Comment: What do you mean by converge or diverge? Are you referring to the series $\sum_i x_i$?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I am referring to the results of both summations.

Comment: Write out the corresponding matrix as in the linked question to get the eigenvalues ${ 1\over 2} ( \alpha \pm \sqrt{\alpha^2 -4})$. For $|\alpha| >2$, it certainly diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really the same question since the recursion is $v_{n+1}=Av_n$ where $v_n$ is the column vector $v_n=\begin{pmatrix}x_{n+1}\\ x_{n}\end{pmatrix}$ and $A$ is the $2\times2$ matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$. Thus $v_n=A^nv_0$ for every $n$ and, if the eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ of $A$ are distinct, there exists some constants $(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4)$ such that $x_n=(c_1\lambda_1^n+c_2\lambda_2^n)x_0+(c_3\lambda_1^n+c_4\lambda_2^n)x_1$ for every $n\geqslant0$.

If $|\lambda_1|\lt1$ and $|\lambda_2|\lt1$, then, for every initial condition $(x_1,x_0)$, $x_n\to0$ when $n\to\infty$. Finally, note that $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the roots of the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(x)=\det(xI-A)=x^2-ax+1$ hence $\lambda_1\lambda_2=1$ and it is impossible that $|\lambda_1|\lt1$ and $|\lambda_2|\lt1$.

Note that $a=2+h^2\lambda$ hence $\chi_A(1)=\chi'_A(1)=2-a=-h^2\lambda$. If $h^2\lambda\gt0$, then $\chi_A(1)=\chi'_A(1)\lt0$ hence one eigenvalue is real and larger than $1$ and there is explosion.

Comment: You did convince me that approaching this problem with matrices is easier, however I did some calculations my self (I added theses to my question) and it seems that it is stable for $2<\alpha<-2$, since then the eigenvalues are complex and both have a magnitude of one. However your answer only says that if $h^\lambda>0$ (so if $\alpha>2$) it would be unstable.

Comment: There is no contradiction.

Comment: @Did I mean that your answer does not cover the entire range of $h^2 \lambda$ and usual the stability regions describe a region in the complex plane.